# How to get last canvas element index wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to wpf, what I wanted to do add 3 buttons and a canvas to xaml. 
Each  button represents a color.

1. yellow
2. green
3. black
   There can be only **one yellow** and only **one green**, and **many black** dots as you want.
   It seemed reasonable to save the index of yellow and green dots after putting them down so they can be accessed later to delete them by their indexes, and then redraw it.
   As long as I use only one color, (the yellow or green dot) everything works fine, but when I apply the buttons in that order: "A B C A B" or (A B A B) the green overrides the black dot.

So my question is, what am I doing wrong? Is there a better way than this?
Is there a better way to get the canvas index than using `canvas.Children.Count;`?

> EDIT: seems like working with indexes is a bit messy, should have store them in UIElement instead

XAML

```
<StackPanel Background="Aqua">
    <Button Click="ButtonA_Click" Width="80">putDOT_A</Button>
    <Button Click="ButtonB_Click" Width="80">putDOT_B</Button>
    <Button Click="ButtonC_Click" Width="80">putDOT_C</Button>
    <Canvas 
            Name="canvas"
            Panel.ZIndex="0"
            Background="White"
            ClipToBounds="true"
            Width="400" Height="400" 
            MouseDown="Canvas_MouseDown" >
    </Canvas>
</StackPanel>
```

CS

```
 {
    public int indexA = -1;
    public int indexB = -1;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void RemoveAxisPoint(int index)
    {
        if (index >= 0)
        {
            canvas.Children.RemoveAt(index - 1);
        }
    }
    private enum MyCurrentButton
    {
        Dot, A, B
    }
    private void Canvas_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (curr)
        {
            case MyCurrentButton.A:
                PutA(e);
                break;
            case MyCurrentButton.B:
                PutB(e);
                break;
            case MyCurrentButton.Dot:
                PutDot(e);
                break;
            default:
                return;
        }
    }
    private void PutDot(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Dot dot = new Dot(canvas);
        dot.Draw(e.GetPosition(canvas));
    }
    private void PutB(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Dot dot = new Dot(canvas,0, 255, 0);
        RemoveAxisPoint(indexB);
        dot.DrawB(e.GetPosition(canvas));
        indexB = canvas.Children.Count;
    }
    private void PutA(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Dot dot = new Dot(canvas, 255, 255, 0);
        RemoveAxisPoint(indexA);
        dot.DrawA(e.GetPosition(canvas));
        indexA = canvas.Children.Count;
    }
    private MyCurrentButton curr = MyCurrentButton.Dot;
    private void ButtonA_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        curr = MyCurrentButton.A;
    }
    private void ButtonB_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        curr = MyCurrentButton.B;
    }
    private void ButtonC_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        curr = MyCurrentButton.Dot;
    }
    class Dot : IDraw
    {
        private readonly Canvas _canvas;
        public Ellipse dot { get; private set; }
        public double Width { get; set; }
        public double Height { get; set; }
        public Brush Fill { get; private set; }
        public Dot(Canvas canvas,  byte r = 0, byte g = 0, byte b = 0)
        {
            _canvas = canvas;
            SolidColorBrush color = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(r, g, b));
            dot = new Ellipse
            {
                Width = 10,
                Height = 10,
                Fill = color
            };
        }
        public void DrawA(Point location)
        {
            Canvas.SetLeft(dot, location.X - (dot.Width / 2));
            Canvas.SetTop(dot, location.Y - (dot.Height / 2));
            _canvas.Children.Add(dot);
        }
        public void DrawB(Point location)
        {
            Canvas.SetLeft(dot, location.X - (dot.Width / 2));
            Canvas.SetTop(dot, location.Y - (dot.Height / 2));
            _canvas.Children.Add(dot);
        }
        public void Draw(Point location)
        {
            Canvas.SetLeft(dot, location.X - (dot.Width / 2));
            Canvas.SetTop(dot, location.Y - (dot.Height / 2));
            _canvas.Children.Add(dot);
        }
    }
    public interface IDraw
    {

        void Draw(Point location);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code doesn't work is that after you delete the first index the second index, if it is greater than the first, is wrong.

So to fix this...

```
 RemoveAxisPoint(indexA);
 if(indexB > indexA)indexB--;
```

and...

```
 RemoveAxisPoint(indexB);
 if(indexA > indexB)indexA--;
```

So this will fix the current issue.  However your design is very brittle and will likely break again as soon as your change it.  I suggest using Canvas.Children.Remove() instead of RemoveAt() which will reduce performance slightly but improve robustness greatly.

Comment: Added the if parts, now it throws "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException"
at the remove, because of the underindexing at "n.RemoveAt(index - 1);"
emblemed it in a trycatch to see if fixing the indexing could fix it, but it's way too much hassle 


I see RemoveAt() is a dead end, how can I store that "dot" in a temporary variable to delete it later with canvas.Children.Remove()?

Comment: seems like storing it in UIElement solved the problem